# Submitting form with get method, cant recieve on other page

Tags: php, html, forms, get

My code is super easy, but yet it's not working. It used to work, but then I changed something up and now I'm back to basic again. Can you guys see why it doesn't work?

**Client code**

```
<h1>Logg inn</h1>
<form method="get" action="herpaderp.php">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" value="Testtittel"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" value="Testbeskrivelse">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="src" value="lollolol.jpg">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Logg inn</button>
</form>
```

**Server code:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET["title"]))
    echo $_GET["title"];
if(isset($_GET["desc"]))
    echo $_GET["desc"];
if(isset($_GET["src"]))
    echo $_GET["src"];
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simple, your form elements need to be named and not as an ID.

You have `id="title"` yet it should be `name="title"` (added to what you presently have)

You can use `id="title"`, but just make sure you also include `name="title"`

- **Do the same for the others**

---

(***A lookahead***) => I also noticed you are using the word `desc` be careful if you're using that in conjunction with a DB, as `desc` is an MySQL [**reserved word**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html), *just saying.*

An example:

The following will throw an error:

```
"INSERT INTO yourTable (desc) VALUES ('value')"
```

Correct method: (using the tick ` character around the column name)

```
"INSERT INTO yourTable (`desc`) VALUES ('value')"
```

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot!! Does this account for POST method too? @Fred -ii-

Comment: @NC.A $_POST is used when somebody pushes data to your application, while $_GET is used when you get from application.

Comment: Yes it does account for POST also, just as SJD pointed out. @NC.A anytime a POST or GET method is looking for a variable, it is looking for a named form element.

Comment: @NC.A `$_REQUEST` is also another global variable, part of the superglobals family.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are changed in the html form or you haven't use name attributes

```
<h1>Logg inn</h1>
<form method="get" action="herpaderp.php">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name='title' value="Testtittel"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" name='desc' value="Testbeskrivelse">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="src" name='src' value="lollolol.jpg">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Logg inn</button>
</form>
```

You can use php code as bellow (But it is same as yours)

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET["title"])) echo $_GET["title"];

if(isset($_GET["desc"]))  echo $_GET["desc"];

if(isset($_GET["src"]))  echo $_GET["src"];

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

`$_GET[]` takes `name="";` property not `id=""`.

So your code will become:

```
<h1>Logg inn</h1>
<form method="get" action="herpaderp.php">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" value="Testtittel"> 
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="desc" name="desc" value="Testbeskrivelse">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="src" name="src" value="lollolol.jpg">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Logg inn</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

As already suggested replace the `id=` of the fields with the `name=`

feature of PHP's processing of **POST** and **GET** variables is that it automatically decodes **indexed form variable names**.

```
<?php
//display the POST or GET parameter
var_dump($_POST);    
?>
```

**Output :**

```
//will get you something like:
 array('title'=>'john','description'=>'smith')
```

But to make this $_POST work 
You Must write in the .HTML file in the form ( `action="http://example.php"`)

To display the submitted data you could simply `echo $_POST;` in The "**example.php**"